# How to display datetime in SourceTree terminal bash

Tags: git, bash, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

This is referring to the git Terminal that can be launched from the Atlassian SourceTree desktop client on Windows (7). I just want to be able to see the datetime for when a command was run. Right now all I see when I run a git command in this Terminal is:

```
username@machine MINGW64 /path/to/git/dir (branch)
```

I want to see something like:

```
2016-06-22T21:01:48+00:00 username@machine MINGW64 /path/to/git/dir (branch)
```

Where can I edit the .bashrc file to show this? I can't find an option in the SourceTree desktop client.

Comment: I think you can in the git terminal `cd ~` to witch to your local directory,  and edit `.profile` and more precisely the environment variable PS1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the path of git used by SourceTree (embedded or external git), you can modify `<git>\etc\profile.d\git-prompt.sh` with:

```
PS1="$PS1"'\w \t'             # current working directory
```

The `\t` will add the timestamp to the git bash prompt:

```
vonc@voncavn7 MINGW64 /d/git/tests/subm/p1 23:45:37 (master)
```

[image: git bash timestamp]